# How do you group multiple fields of a view when the last item is a link?

Tags: views, theming

I'm grouping multiple fields of a view into a single div by hiding the first fields and rewriting the content of the last field using variables.  The problem is that the last field is a Link node which causes my rewritten content to be wrapped by a link tag.  I only want the link tag around this element where I placed it as a variable.  Is there a way to remove the link tag around the entirety of the rewritten field?

Also, the link node itself is placed as plain text when represented by the [variable].  I would like it to be a link.

Comment: I ended up creating a dummy text field at the end to be rewritten instead of the link field.  This works, but I'm open to a more elegant solution.

Comment: Don't need to create a dummy text field, just switch the last two fields ie LINK field and above the LINK field. Exclude the LINK field and rewrite above the LINK field, and show the fields as you like.